# PySpark : Stream the same file continuously

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have written below code, and it works perfectly. When a new file is added to the directory, the data is picked up and loaded into the data frame.

Now am trying to stream the same file, eg: Job.csv is my file, if any new data is appended to the file, spark should automatically read that data and load into a dataframe. Same file should be streamed continuously. Do we have this option, i don't find any documentation for this. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Below is my existing code,

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
SqlContext = pyspark.SQLContext(sc)
spark = SparkSession(sc)

userSchema = StructType().add('JOB_ID', 'string')\
    .add('JOB_TITLE', 'string')\
    .add('MIN_SALARY', 'integer')\
    .add('MAX_SALARY', 'integer')

dfCSV = spark.readStream.option('sep', ',')\
    .option('header', 'false')\
    .schema(userSchema)\
    .csv('C:/Hadoop/Data/Job*.csv')

dfCSV.createOrReplaceTempView('job')

data = spark.sql('select * from job')

console = data.writeStream.outputMode(outputMode='Append').format('console').start()

console.awaitTermination()
```